# An efficient algorithm to compute a line digraph from a digraph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, linegraph

Does anyone know an efficient algorithm to compute a line digraph from a digraph?  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph (The Wikipedia article mentions the digraph case near the bottom (in the Generalizations sections).  Ideally I would like to do this in linear time.

From that section:

- If G is a directed graph, its directed line graph or line digraph has one vertex for each edge of G.
- Two vertices representing directed edges from u to v and from w to x in G are connected by an edge from uv to wx in the line digraph when v = w.

Let G be the directed graph
Let L(G) be the directed line graph

The algorithm I can come up with to produce L(G) given G is:

- Iterate through all edges of G to produce the nodes of L(G)
- Iterate through all pairs of nodes (uv, wx) in L(G) and connect if v = w

This is an O(n^2) algorithm.

Seems like there should be a way to get this down to O(n) time.  I'm going to go think about this, but I figured I'd ask stack overflow just in case there's some famous (or not so famous) algorithm for doing this that I don't know of.

Comment: I'm guessing the best way to go about this is to change the second step "iterate through all pairs of nodes (uv, wc) in L(G)...)" so that its instead "iterate through all nodes v in G".

Comment: Then for every incoming edge uv and outgoing edge vx there will be an edge in L(G) (between nodes uv and vx).  Although that still sounds like an O(n^2) algorithm.  Maybe there's some kind of amortized analysis for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't exape from O(n^2), because there are some graph with a linear graph with a cardinality of the edges equals to the square of the cardinality of the the vertices of the original one: think, for example, at a graph with n+1 vertices, with a single vertex connected to other all vertices: you have then to build a clique with n vertices, so with (n-1)^2 edges.

The complexity of an algorithm is bounded from the bottom by the size of the output it produces.

This, of course, doesn't mean we don't have to find smart algorithms. I've thinked at that:

```
LG(LN,LE) getLinearGraph(G(N,E)) {
  LN = EmptySet();
  LE = EmptySet();
  for (Vertex v : N) {
    verticesToAdd = EmptySet()
    for (Vertex i : out-degree(v) {
      toAdd += textual-rep((v,i));
    }
    LN += toAdd;
    LE += make-clique(toAdd);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your example. Do you mean G is this: www.cs.colostate.edu/~stonea/stkimg/g.png (I'm not sure how to embed images into comments here). In which case the line graph would just be the nodes {ab, ac, ad, ...} and no edges.

Comment: Though I suspect you're right that there can be a quadratic blow-up of edges in L(G).  I can think of cases where L(G) has more edges than G (the one in the wikipedia article for instance).

Comment: The line graph is directed, but the original one is not, so yes, if you count those edges as undirected, you have my example.

Comment: You can see what I mean by the wikipedia example: 3 is connected with 1 and 4, and in the line graph we have an embedded clique with nodes (1,3), (1,4), (3,4).

Comment: Oh okay, I see.  Right, you'd get a clique with this: www.cs.colostate.edu/~stonea/stkimg/g2.png

Comment: So, if you have a single node connected with all the other nodes (and no other edges), you just get a giant clique.

Comment: Or actually no, I wouldn't get a clique with that g2 image I just linked.  In L(G) there would be an edge ba,ab but no edge ab,ac).  But that's still O(n^2) edges.

Comment: But I don't understand why are you talking about directed graphs, when the problem is related to undirected ones.

Comment: The specific problem I have is converting a directed graph to a directed line graph.  The Wikipedia article is mostly about undirected graphs, but the algorithm I'm going to need to code is for the directed case.

Comment: Oh, then you should state more explicitly that on the question, I've only read the wikipedia article ;)

Comment: Thought it was clear from the title of the question :-), but I've just edited my Q to try and make it more clear.

Thanks for your input though, I've learned something about graph theory today, and even in the directed case there can be an O(n^2) blow-up of edges (the g2 image an example of such).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I think there may be a more time-efficient algorithm after some thought too... but it would require a fair amount of book-keeping and a chunk of extra memory to do so.

My basic thoughts are that you loop over all the nodes in G and create connected nodes from the edges connected to each node. With an extra link to keep track of G(edge) to L(G)(node) you may be able to get away with just one loop through the nodes on G.